# How to set timeout for CallKit incoming call UI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, voip, callkit

I'm developing Video call feature in my app and using CallKit to be the incoming call UI. And i found an edge case like:

- User A: call user B
- User B:

  - The app is in terminated state. And CallKit incoming UI shows for user B.
  - User B doesn't notice (since silent mode) and let the incoming UI keep showing
  - User A doesn't end the call; or for some reasons, user A lost internet or quit the app (therefore my server doesn't send Cancel command via VoIP notification) so there's no way for user B to end the incoming UI until user B touch Cancel or Answer

So is there any way to set a timeout for an incoming UI of CallKit? For example: If i set the timeout is 60 seconds then the incoming UI just shows in 60 seconds the auto dismiss.

Here is my code to show the incoming UI:

```
let update = CXCallUpdate()
update.localizedCallerName = callerName
update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: myID)
update.hasVideo = true
        
self.provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update) { [weak self] error in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    if error == nil {
        // Store my calls
        let call = Call(uuid: uuid, handle: handle)
        self.callKitManager.add(call: call)
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to set a timeout using the `CallKit` API. You just have to implement it by yourself.

In the class where you handle all the call logic, you should add something like the following:

```
private func startRingingTimer(for call: Call)
{
    let vTimer = Timer(
        timeInterval: 60,
        repeats: false,
        block: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.ringingDidTimeout(for: call)
        })
    vTimer.tolerance = 0.5
    RunLoop.current.add(vTimer, forMode: .common)
    ringingTimer = vTimer
}

private func ringingDidTimeout(for call: Call)
{
    ...
    self.provider.reportCall(with: call.uuid, endedAt: nil, reason: .unanswered)
    ...
}
```

Then you should call `startRingingTimer(for: call)` as soon as you successfully reported a new incoming call; and, of course, you have to invalidate the timer if the user answers the call.

Comment: Thanks, i found the way for this. I create a timer in case incoming call is reported in active state; otherwise, i create a background task to handle the timeout.

Comment: You don't need to distinguish between active and inactive states. As long as there's an active CallKit call, your app is running and you don't need to create a background task.

Comment: Seems a good point, but let me think about that later since my background task is working good for now. Thanks mate @Marco